# No overload for method 'ToDictionary' takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

Actually i should work, from my point of view, I don't know whats wrong,the problem is that `item`and `value`do not have a `ToDictionary()`.

Maybe you can take a look ?!

Method signature:
`public static IDictionary<string, object> ListO(this object instance)`

My Code:

```
 if (instance == null)
                throw new NullReferenceException();

            var result = instance as IDictionary<string, object>;
            if (result != null)
                return result;

            return instance.GetType()
                .GetProperties()
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x =>
                {
                    object value = x.GetValue(instance);

                    if (value != null)
                    {
                        var valueType = value.GetType();

                        // Whe should manually check for string type because IsPrimitive will return false in case of string
                        if (valueType.IsPrimitive || valueType == typeof(string))
                        {

                            return value;
                        }
                        else if (valueType.GetInterfaces().Any(t => t == typeof(IEnumerable)))
                        {
                            List<object> elements = new List<object>();

                            foreach (var item in value as IEnumerable)
                            {
                                elements.Add(item.ToDictionary());//problem here
                            }

                            return elements;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return value.ToDictionary();//problem here
                        }

                    }
                    return null;
                });
```

I get :

> No overload for method 'ToDictionary' takes 0 arguments

What did I wrong ?

Comment: 1) trying to use `ToDictionary()` on a single item 2) using a method signature from `ToDictionary` that doesn't exist.

Comment: what are you actually trying to do? are you expecting these to be dictionaries? Or these are IEnumerable which you want to convert to Dictionaries?

Comment: The method should read property names as string and its values as objects, based on reflection, sometime the given object can have subobjects which are list or some other types, that is what the metthod should take care of. It should return the given object to string(property name) and its values as objects

Comment: Why not then just `var dict = instance.GetType().GetProperties().ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.GetValue(instance));` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
elements.Add(item.ToDictionary(e => e.Key,e => e.Value))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) will help people understand the reasons for your code suggestion.